# Can I perform an onClick event and a <NavLink to="/Scooters"> at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After clicking the search button, I can filter my database, but at the same time I would like to redirect to another route where I can show the results of the query in a table. Is this possible in React? I am using `<BrowserRouter>`. That would be also great if I could redirect from the onClick event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible in React. Using `history.push`

install history module

```
npm install --save history
```

and then import it and do something like below in your onclick event handler

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createHistory()

onClickEventHandler = () => {
  history.push("/path");
}
```

or use context.router to navigate like

```
this.context.router.push('/path');
```

Comment: Hi, using this.context.history i receive Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. Do I have to import something? Thank you!

Comment: @Alex94 Sorry my bad it is actually this.context.router.push('/path'); I updated my answer please give a try

Comment: this.context.router.push('/path'); well, do I need npm i --save history for this? I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: No not required

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined what I get

Comment: I'm using <BrowserRouter>

Comment: Are you using react-router-redux module? do you have redux actions used in your component?

Comment: I'm not using Redux.

Answer (score 0):

Way 1.

You can use state variable and redirect to relevent page also you can pass params and you can get it inside the component

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

if (this.state.page === 'SEARCH') {
     return <Redirect to="/searchPage" />;
} else if (this.state.page === 'DETAIL') {
     return <Redirect to="/detailPage" />;
} else {
   return 'render component here'

}
```

Way 2 :- 
  You can redirect through context also like below and similarly you can pass object as parmas as a second parameter
   and you need to context in constructor also
Import PropTypes in your component

```
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
```

Add Context Types under your component

```
static contextTypes = {
        router: PropTypes.object
    }
```

Call constructor with context

```
constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
}
```

In code method you can call below code to navigate to another page

```
this.context.router.history.push('/searchPage');
```

For both the option you don't need Redux

Comment: Hi there, I get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

Comment: static contextTypes = {
        router: PropTypes.object
    }  Add this in your component and check Updated answer for reference

Comment: Way 1: 'Redirect' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef, maybe I need this: import { Redirect } from 'react-router'

Comment: Redirect is part of react-router-dom module